# C++ Vector subscript out of range line 1201

Tags: c++, loops, vector

So I had to write n-amount of real numbers into vector and then print the biggest from it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void printMax(vector<double>);

int main()
{
    vector<double> vct;
    double n;

    while(cin >> n)
        vct.push_back(n);

    printMax(vct);
    return 0;
}

void printMax(vector<double> x)
{
    int max;

    for(int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++)
    {
        if(x[i] > x[i - 1]) max = x[i];
        else continue;
    }

    cout << "Max = \t" << max << endl;
}
```

When I start this program it lets me to enter numbers but as soon as I press ctrl+z and enter it crashes and says : vector subscript out of the range line: 1201. I think that an issue is with void `printMax` part .

Comment: It stands for something else :) @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to start the following loop with `i = 1`:

```
for (int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++){
    if (x[i] > x[i - 1])
        max = x[i];
    // else continue superfluous
}
```

because if `i` is `0`, `i - 1` will be negative one (or the biggest value of `unsigned int` there is). That's not possibly a valid index in this case.

Also, why are you using `int` for said real numbers?

**In fact**, there's a simpler way to find the maximum element of a vector. It does not involve a comparison of the two consecutive elements, but rather comparison of the current `max` against each element. Improve your algorithm, or perhaps, use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

And when I wrote **improve**, I actually meant **correct** it.

Comment: Your code suggestion allows `max` to be read while uninitialized in some cirucmstances; also it isn't the right logic for finding the maximum of the set

Comment: If I may ask, what circumstances? And... this is not about `std::set`.

Comment: if `x[i] > x[i-1]` is never true, then `max` is never set within the loop.  I wasn't talking about `std::set`. By "set" I mean the values which we are trying to find the maximum of.

Comment: I thought you meant my later lines... That code isn't a suggestion at all... It just doesn't crash. `max` is only being written, not read, the only way `max` will equal the biggest element is that the vector has more than two elements and the very last is the largest. Wrong code, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

In the `for` loop, when `i = 0` you are accessing `x[i - 1]` (i.e. `x[-1]`).

You may want to change to

```
int max = x[0];
for (int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++){
    if(x[i] > max) max = x[i]; // Compare with actual max
```

Answer (score 3):

in the first round of your for loop `x=0` and you use `x[i - 1]` ie. `x[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

If your first index is 0, then the line `x[i] > x[i - 1]` becomes `x[0] > x[-1]`, and `x[-1]` is always out if bounds. Change your loop to start at `int i = 1` and it should resolve your problem.